# Как из полученного файла JSON вывести в консоль строку, полученную по ключу?

Tags: javascript, json

К примеру, у меня есть json файл, записи в котором имеют такой вид:

**token_data.json**

```
{
"latitude":"45,24368",
"longitude":"38,97343",
"velocity":"6",
"distance":"0",
"date":"11.34.2021_12:34:15",
"azimuth":"112,8"
}
```

А извлекаю их с помощью такого скрипта:

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(addLayerPointTracker, 3000);
});
function addLayerPointTracker() {
    fetch("../token_data.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data)) //вывод в консоль полученных значений из json файла с интервалом в 3 секунды.
}
```

Была идея получить строку таким способом:
`.then(data => console.log([0].data))`, но она не увенчалась успехом
Каким способом я могу получить, к примеру строку, с ключом "longitude" и значением "38,97343"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что token_data.json - объект, доступ до longitude должен быть таким

```
.then(data => console.log(data.longitude))
```